# Swig lua object from interpreter

Tags: c++, c, lua, swig

I'm sometimes getting lua variables directly from interpreter from within my C++ code not related to swig, for instance

```
lua_getglobal( mpLuaState, varname );
double var = lua_tonumber(mpLuaState, -1);
lua_setglobal( mpLuaState, varname );
```

When I try to take some custom object with

```
void * = lua_touserdata(mpLuaState, -1);
```

I realized that SWIG is wrapping custom objects with SWIG_NewPointerObj.

Is there any way to get a pointer value to my custom object?

@edit

I've just came up with a workaround for this issue.
I've added a method to my class exported to lua with Swig,

`unsigned long GetPtr();`

which is returning

`return (unsigned long)this;`

and then when I want to take it from C++ code (not related to Swig but only with pointer to `Lua_state*`),
run script with

`luaL_doString("ptrVal = MyObj:GetVal")`

and then take it as normal number and parse it to `void*`

This is just workaround and I'd like to do it properly.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `SWIG_ConvertPtr`

Comment: @HenriMenke Like I've said, I'm not trying to do it from within Swig, so I don't have any SWIG_ConvertPtr functionality.

Comment: Then I wish you good luck trying to extract the definition of [`SWIG_Lua_ConvertPtr` from the SWIG source](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/df86ec5af6985fc1ada3945237dcf34113db6512/Lib/lua/luarun.swg#L1762-L1796).

Comment: “I'd like to do it properly” By not doing it from within SWIG you have already abandoned this goal.

Comment: ok, could I generate a function using Swig that is getting raw pointer to memory? I imagine that it should check for type and use SWIG_ConvertPtr. But the problem is that at this point in my code I have only variable interpreter name and C++ type.

Comment: If you are linking against the SWIG module, you can just copy the prototype of `SWIG_Lua_ConvertPtr` as an `extern` declaration to your file and [export the runtime in SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Modules_external_run_time).